# How to work with dynamic cell height using auto layout in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to change the height according to content of cell. I don't want to calculate height every time for each text. This should also work for any with of text means label should update on its orientation change also.

Is there any feasible way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer link below. This is the best way to do exactly what you want.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout